# What is the Quantum mechanical explanation of the London dispersion interactions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dispersion

How can I simply quantum mechanically explain the spontaneous dipole mechanism which leads to dispersion interactions between two atoms or molecules.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons in the bonding molecular orbitals occupy positions between the cores of the atoms which make the molecule.Once the wavefunctions of the electrons is collapsed by interacting with the environment there is small probability the electrons are closer to one of the nuclei creating an electric dipole.This affects the electrons of molecules close to that molecule , the electrons are repelled or attracted from the dipole.